# Get height of children when floating left

Tags: css, css-float

I have a parent div and inside two child div which are floating left. What I am trying to get is that get the 100% height depending upon the child. So if one child is bigger then the whole container should have its height.

This is my scss

```
.whole-message-wrapper {
width: 100%;

.message-info-wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 5%;

    .message-icons {
        .message {
        }

        .attachment {
        }
    }
}

.message-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
}
}
```

I don't want to have fixed height, any ideas?

So I want the yellow child to have the same height as the parent.

[image]

Comment: HTML? Snippet? Flexbox?

Comment: Make the parent height field to `auto`. It will wrap according to heigh of the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix these kind of issues using Flex. Apply `display:flex` for your parent, It will fix the issue.

```css
   .whole-message-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

.message-info-wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
}

.message-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole-message-wrapper">
  <div class="message-info-wrapper">Message Info Wrapper</div>
  <div class="message-wrapper">
  <p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: No need for 100% & floats, and the width should be defined the flexbox way, flex: ... or just flex-basis: ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox`, without `float`

**HTML**

```
<div class="whole-message-wrapper">
    <div class="message-info-wrapper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, harum.</div>
    <div class="message-wrapper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, harum.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.whole-message-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.message-info-wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 5%;

}

.message-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    width: 95%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ht7mt3u1/7/